# Rails 3 -- Rspec

Tags: windows, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2

in my rails3 app I have installed rspec. But when I run the rspec command in my console it gives the following error.

```
C:\myapp>rspec spec
'rspec' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Please Help.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
bundle exec rspec spec
```

It doesnt solve the root problem, but is a quick work-around

EDIT: Did a bit of googling for you, have you tried this? http://getsatisfaction.com/railstutorial/topics/rspec_command_not_found#reply_4313182

Comment: I know about this work around. But I wanted to know the root cause of this. Though thanks for your answer. It might be helpful to others. :)

Comment: You should probably some sort of windows tag to the question, as thats really what it is, rather than rails specific :)

Comment: @Rohit Added some info to my answer, check it out

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the ruby gems directory to your PATH environment variable.

For me this is "C:\Program Files\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems", but this will vary depending on version and install directory. You can add it to your PATH variable by going to Computer > System Properties > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variable > Path > Edit. Make sure you don't wipe the existing contents. Instead, add a semi-colon and paste the gems path in.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I did this and it worked

```
C:\OSS\InSpects>PATH=C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\bin;C:\Ruby192\bin
```

Comment: Hi, where did you add this to run this, as command in command prompt or the path? I mean I dint get this particular thing `C:\OSS\Inspects>Path=`

Comment: nevermind, I got it I just placed `C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\bin` in the path :) but would like to know what you have done above.